# highcharts display hour minute on x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

please do help me, i need to display a 3 hour graph with there minutes using highchart.

please see screenshot

thank you so much[image]

Comment: it's always better if you start by making a jsfiddle file for the users. Is handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extend the code below with your data

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    defaultSeriesType: 'line',
    marginRight: 130,
    marginBottom: 25
},
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts',
    x: -20 //center
},
subtitle: {
    text: ' ',
    x: -20
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                    '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: ' '
    },
    plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'}]
},
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -10,
    y: 100,
    borderWidth: 0
},
series: [    
{
    name: 'Time',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]}]
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/CA2cT/9/

Comment: thanks @mangobug. 

but how can i group the labels on x axis. aside from the minute i also have to indicate their respective hour as the header

please see attached image


super thanks!